# Magento 2: CURL response into array

Tags: magento-2.1.3

I am getting this response in magento 2 curl. Do you know, how we can convert this response into array?

Here is my code:

```
$this->curlClient->post($url, $post);
$responseCurl = $this->curlClient->getBody();
print_r($responseCurl);
```

Current O/P:

```
{"status":true,"data":{"name":null,"start":"2018-04-19 11:07:02","end":"2018-04-19 11:07:02","discount_type":"P","discount_amount":12,"code":"abc_123"}}
```

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

Try [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
 $this->curlClient->post($url, $post);
$responseCurl = $this->curlClient->getBody();
$data = json_decode($responseCurl, TRUE);
print_r($data);
```

The second parameter will make json string into an associative arrays.

Comment: its not working in magento 2.1.3

Comment: It's PHP standard code it should work , I have tested it on my pc and working fine with your json data

Comment: Yes but its not working with magento CURL